# rails console pry/irb "stuck" after displaying long value/string

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, irb, pry

I am developing with rails on a mac using the rails console via pry/irb.

When I display a long result in the console ie. Model.all or .really_long_string, I cant seem to get past the string or value that is displayed and the console displays "(END)" at the end of the console.

What command do I use to get past this so I can continue entering ruby statements on the console without having to close the terminal window?

I recently discovered Ctrl Z to close the console, but I assume there is a better way

Comment: When Pry opens up the irb, type in "exit"

Comment: For those who come to this page looking for your own answers: `CTRL + C`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15958146/rails-console-end-how-to-get-past-it

Comment: Press "q" as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15958146/rails-console-end-how-to-get-past-it

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Looks likes the END is made by a pager. Have u tried typing "q"?

Comment: I've been looking for this very answer for weeks. I had gotten into the habit of just opening a new terminal window whenever it would get stuck.

Comment: The gift that keeps on giving. :)