# Rails console (END) how to get past it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-console

working in the Rails console, I pasted a very long hash into the console and when I scrolled ot the bottom of it it has the token (END) but the only way I've found to get past it is to exit the console with CTRL+Z.  This defeats my purpose in using the console for testing some code out.  Is there any other way to get past that (END) token?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

stumbled over this problem, after some tries I found the solution :)

<strike>⇧ `shift`</strike> + **Q**

**Edit:** as mentioned by @Paul, only `Q` will suffice.

Comment: you're right, somehow I automatically used the `shift`, updated my answer

Answer (score -1):

What about Ctrl+C? It should continue without exiting the console.

Comment: Nope, I just got a BEEP and the (END) remains